# How to implement "user Comment" in asp.net mvc4 applictaion?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement user Comment in my application.[It similar to Facebook comments],In without page loading i need to show the user added comments[con-currently many user can added his own comment] , anybody please help me to findout the Solution,

Thanks Advance,

Comment: Add some code with what you already have. This is not enough information to help you with the solution

Comment: @RalphJansen- I tried with the normal textarea and submit button while saving on that i get the list and binding the model normaly.

Comment: @Rajesh_Bangalore then what's the problem? You just save the content of the textarea in your database and load all the comments when needed.

Comment: @marthijn But that Only Listout after page  getting reloaded,i want do this without page loading

Comment: @Rajesh_Bangalore use an Ajax form (i.e. replace the form with the comment-html when it is saved).

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to look at a third party library to do this. A good one which the site I work for has implemented is [disqus](http://disqus.com/). It's easy to implement and just requires a bit of html and javascript to get working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own, go through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/436536/Social-News) wonderfull article which uses Knockout.js with FluentNHibernate framework(you can use EF or ADO.NET). I'm damn sure you won't get better than this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/436536/Social-News

Or else, use [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) (third party tool).
you can use this example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559728/An-Introduction-to-Disqus-Pluggable-Commenting-Sys

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax.BeginForm method to draw that particular form. I hope this will give you a clue on how to achieve the same.